# Exporting pictures from Excel to Multiple Slides in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, image, import, export, powerpoint

So last week I was working on creating some macros to build [randomized bingo cards with pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789696/excel-vba-to-build-bingo-cards-with-pictures-instead-of-numbers/26808578#26808578). I have succeeded in this goal but now I'm trying to take randomized columns of those pictures (the numbers/pictures selected) and import them in the order they were randomized into PowerPoint in separate slides to be able to show the picture selected for each pick.

Does anyone have any ways to achieve this goal? I know I can import the pictures as a photo album from the folder they are in on the desktop but that requires you to reorganize them on the import or within PowerPoint.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  How to insert a picture from a file onto a PPT slide, given the path to the picture file? Or must the pictures come from out of Excel?  In which case, is there a specific reason why they SHOULD be in Excel rather than just keeping references to the picture file on disk?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I've built bingo cards with pictures instead of numbers.

I've used the same macro that I used to build the cards to pick the numbers (pictures in my case) that will be called out for each space (i.e. B - Bob).

I'm trying to find an easier way to import all of these randomized pictures into PowerPoint so we are able to just go through each slide for each selection.

I know how to import a photo album but that makes it a little difficult to reorganize them in the order desired. I was just trying to see if there was an easier solution that someone might be aware of.

Comment: Again:  do you want to know how to insert a picture from a file onto a slide in PowerPoint?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I'm trying to insert 75 pictures that are in excel in one column into PowerPoint with each cell/picture getting its own slide.